# Why Eclipse does't show error if we don't use main method in program.

Tags: java

I have written a simple program on eclipse tool without using the main method.  It is running my another program. Why it does not give any error or warnings.

Comment: You don't need a `main` method in your project - the project could also serve as a jar library for another project. The `main()` method is just the very first method which is launched by the virtual machine - depending on your environment, this could for example als be provided by some application container like a J2EE server.

Comment: please enclose your project structure. Run it as configuration you will see error as main method not found

Answer (score 1):

because `main` method is not necessary if you don't want to execute a Java class as an independent program.

Congrats. You have created an object :)